# How to add string $action in form

Tags: php

I have this php code in my register.php file:

```
// include the Zebra_Form class
require 'system/Zebra_Form.php';

// instantiate a Zebra_Form object
$form = new Zebra_Form('register_form');
```

I now want to add action which will go to action="?do=register"

This is the class [Zebra_Form](http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Form/Zebra_Form/Zebra_Form.html):

```
void Zebra_Form ( 
    string $name , 
    [ string $method = 'POST'] , 
    [ string $action = ''] , 
    [ array $attributes = ''] )
```

Please guide me where to write action URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really want "?do=register" as your action:

```
$form = new Zebra_Form('register_form', 'POST', '?do=register');
```

The action in your Zebra_Form is the third parameter. You have to explicitly specify a value for the second option parameter in order to be able to set the third parameter. I'm assuming you want 'POST' here which you usually would.